# VS Code Python Interactive Window Cannot find Conda Env

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Everytime I try to execute my python code to the Python Interactive Window I get the below error...

```
Executing code failed : Error: Activating Python 3.7.3 64-bit ('base': conda) to run Jupyter failed with Error: 
Command failed: "H:/My Documents/Continuum/anaconda3/Scripts/activate" && conda activate base && 
echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python 
c:/Users/paul.victor/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py python: 
can't open file 'H:\My': [Errno 2] No such file or directory .
```

I have a feeling I'm supposed to try to remap my vscode/python extension that is installed in the C drive to where my anaconda is saved which is the H drive, but I'm not sure how to do that in the vs code settings.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Follow Up to Original**

user8408080 was correct that removing the space did help.  I also modified the path to the anaconda environment to my companies drive nomenclature,

instead of H: it used something like \\company\user...

Now that I fixed that it's kicking out another error saying the system cannot find the path specified even though the path is correct.

```
Executing code failed : Error: Activating Python 3.7.3 64-bit ('base': conda) to run 
Jupyter failed with Error: Command failed:\\apachecorp.com\files\SanAntonio\Home\Paul.Victor\Documents\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate base && 
echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && 
python c:/Users/paul.victor/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py The system cannot find the path specified. .
```

Comment: It seems like you need to escape the space in the directory name. Spaces in names always mess something up

Comment: If the system says it can't find the path, then it's most likely correct in at least some way. First be really sure, that the file exists on the right computer at the path `c:/Users/paul.victor/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py`. Secondly, it might be a good idea to check rights

Comment: It does exist.  The weird thing here is that it was working for months then all of a sudden it stopped working.  I'm not sure if there was a recent update to it or what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your `Anaconda` in `PATH` and `Python Path` in `VSCode` are pointing in different places.

First, check under system variables that your Anaconda is mapped to `PATH` based off where it is installed.

1- Click Start Menu Windows logo, type "path" click on "edit the system environment labels"

2- Under `PATH` for User Variables, if `VSCode` installed correctly to it, you will see the location of the `bin` file. Add to the `PATH` variable if it is not there. Mine looked like `C:\Users\hSin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`

3 - Under `PATH` for System Variables, if `Anaconda` installed correctly to it, you will see the associated paths. There are multiple files/directories that should be a part here. Verify existence before adding as some of these are specific to when Anaconda installed and what settings you chose.

`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`; `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64`; `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin`; `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin`; `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts`

4 - Once all `Path` setups of Anaconda are confirmed, you should be able to call `python` from the terminal regardless of directory terminal is in. If not, your `VSCode` doesn't have the correct interpreter mapped. Go to `VSCode -> File -> Preferences -> Settings` and then search as below to find the `Python:Python Path` setting. It should map to the root installation of your `Anaconda`. Standard is `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`

[image: VSCode Settings]

5 - If still not working, your installations went to haywire and will require a reinstall of both applications. Install `Anaconda` first, make sure to check off the box to add to `PATH`, this is not default checked in the base installation. Then install VSCode, and set as default text editor. The `Anaconda` extension pack should come up as recommended, which will tie the two softwares together seamlessly if installed after Anaconda.

Comment: Yeah, something happened to the installation.  I just uninstalled Anaconda & VSC then installed Anconda then VSC & now it works perfect now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was using Powershell on vscode instead of cmd.
What worked for me was to open a new cmd terminal on vscode. Then I switched to my conda env using:

```
conda activate my_env_name
```

After running this the option of `my_env_name` started showing in the select python interpreter drop down

Answer (score 2):

BEFORE UNINSTALLING AND REINSTALLING AS A LAST RESORT:

In addition to hSin's answer, in VSCode settings, set the "Python: Conda Path" to the root directory of your Anaconda Install folder (The same path you set "Python: Python Path" to).  This did the trick for me, so it's worth a shot before uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Please explain why this is a solution. What does your solution do, how does it solve the problem. (It should also have an educational effect on people who find this question because they have a similar problem. )

Answer (score 2):

According to hSin's answer, I just set the following path to system environment variables of `PATH`:

1. `c:\users\[username]\anaconda3`
2. `c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\Scripts`
3. `c:\users\[username]\anaconda3\Library\bin`

Then restart VS Code, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Install ipykernel in your conda env for it to get detected for .ipynb in visual studio code

```
pip install ipykernel
```