# How to fix Visual Studio Code Jupyter notebook error?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

VScode for python runs perfectly, without any error, problems starts whenever I try to run Jupyter notebook inside VScode.
It starts with Ipython Kernel loading and then it shows Command Failed Error. Any fix for this ? I have no idea what's the problem and I don't know much about the environment and stuffs also.

Thank You.

[image: The Error I'm getting, first an Ipython kernel loading is shown then followed by this error.]

Comment: from the error it seems that is trying to activate an anaconda environment. you could provide more info on how you've set up the environment and what you are trying to achieve, maybe someone can help you then

Comment: I'm just trying to run simple " Hello World" and  just an "import numpy" command, on a notebook inside Vscode. That's all, and i'm getting that error, honestly I don't even know what that error is and that's why I don't know what extra information to provide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502466/vs-code-python-interactive-window-cannot-find-conda-env this works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your picture, VSCode said Command failed, and it's a very long command. It mainly includes two parts: activate the conda base environment and change the vscode python environment through "Python" extension. And from the top right of the picture, it shows the jupyter server start failed.

So you can try to do two things:

First one: change the environment. Instead of using conda, download and install a global python from the official website. And recommend creating a virtual environment. Then select the environment instead of conda base environment.

Second one: reinstall or downgrade the 'Python' extension(if the first one not work).

This problem can be caused by the package in the environment, so I recommend you just change to another environment.

Comment: First of all thanks. I did as you asked, download a global python and create a virtual environment, and test on it and it works. Problem is no way I can make it work with Conda Base Environment. I saw while running the code, it tried to activate the conda base environment from Windows power shell and got that, "Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'. If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change......", error message, maybe if that can be fixed, it can also run on Conda Environment.